# Customize webpack DevServer message

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Currently, when I start my Webpack DevServer, it outputs this message:

`i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/`

Is it possible to somehow customize the url in message to my current project path, which is in my case: `http://localhost:8080/myProject`. The motivation behind that is, that now I need to add `myProject` to browser url bar when the project starts.

Comment: No, it is not possible, you could use the open property

Comment: @Gabriel how did you configure it to be hosted in `/myproject`
Could you share the relevant part of the configuration?
I tried `public` and `publicPath` but i couldn't make it work

Comment: @LuisFilipe well, back in the day, I configured the whole app based on this guide: [angular webpack guide](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well, as stated in the comments there is no option to customize just the message and of course you can use the open property. Although you can always overwrite the internal log function that `Webpack DevServer` uses.

```js
devServer: {
  before: function(app, server) {
    let _info = server.log.info;
    server.log.info = (...args) => {
      return _info(...(args.map(s => typeof s === 'string' ?
        s.replace(/(http:\/\/localhost:8080\/)/, '$1myProject') :
        s
      )));
    }
  }
}
```

That way every message will pass first from this "proxy" function, and if `http://localhost:8080` is found as part of the message it will be replaced with `http://localhost:8080/myProject`. Of course it can be customized further to handle different ports and hostname but I think is good enough to solve this visual issue!

Comment: Where can we write this? Especially when we have custom-webpack.config.js file